# Django forms - editing data in ClearableFileInput

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working with Django forms and i came across the problem with `ClearableFileInput` field - i don't know how to update it from view.

In the view, when the user doesn't upload any file, i want it to set manually - but i cant override any form methods, because the form is 3rd party app. I know i can edit data like this:

```
if 'POST' == request.method:
    form = FormClass(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.cleaned_data['some_field'] = some_new_data
```

When the some_field is CharField, i know the `some_new_data` should be string.  But i don't know what to put in `some_new_data`  when the field is ClearableFileInput. I want to set image which is stored on the website at `MEDIA_ROOT` folder.

Can anyone guide me how to do that? Thanks!